# Django migrations circular dependency what is the best practice?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I would like to know the best practice to handle circular dependency when migrating apps.

Our CRM has two Apps with several model fields depending on each other.

We need to reconstruct the database everyday and this lead us to delete all our existing migration files and create new ones everyday.

In our code the foreign keys are referenced with :

model_name = models.ForeignKey('app.model', ...)

So no issues at runtime.

But at night, when we recreate and apply the migrations, we made a migrate script that basically swaps the foreign keys as IntegerField to prevent CircularDependencyError and reswaps them after the depencies are solved.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: By "regenerate and apply the migrations" do you mean you delete all your existing migration files and create new ones every night?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Comment: Deleting your migrations files regularly makes no sense to me, without a reliable record of schema changes developing in tandom, deploying and rolling-back all become a nightmare once you have data that you cannot lose. If you have two apps that are so closely coupled you should consider refactoring them into a single app otherwise you could create multiple migrations files to create the models and foreign keys in stages and stop deleting your migrations

Comment: @IainShelvington This is legacy code, i have no idea why they choose to recreate migrations everytime. I wanted to know if they were a proper way to do this because changing foreign keys into integers seems like a hack to me.